# Android Studio Logcat does not show errors

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I am very upset about the Android Logcat.
I don't see errors when i run app from my phone.
Logcat doesn't show anything when i try to run an app, but then the app freezes on my smartphone and shuts down.
I cannot develop if logcat doesn't show me any error at all.
If the app runs corretly it will show up.
Things i did to try see an error in Logcat while developing:

- Restarted computer
- Restarted Android studio
- Cleared every single filter from the Logcat in Android Studio
- Executed adb kill-server
- Uninstalled an application that i developed

I am very confused. I need to see a Logcat error to continue developing my application. At the moment i cannot continue developing. Please help me out of trouble!

Things i havent tried yet:

- Reset my phone to factory settings

Comment: When a critical error happens and you see the "Unfortunately [Application Name] has stopped working` message, do you filter `Error` level warnings? That's usually best way to catch what caused the issue, since this crash should be at that level and you can find it easily. Another thing I recommend is not hitting `OK` on the dialog that pops up, sometimes doing so causes more messages to appear that flood afterward and you may lose your spot in Logcat. Hope some of that helps.

Comment: are you running your code directly from android studio to your device or your are running an apk which has been installed previously?

Comment: Try another device/emulator.

Comment: you don't need to reset your phone. go to device tab and see if your phone is connected or not sometimes its connected but in [offline]state. change the target application, most probably now it should be showing "no debuggable apps" or something message. select your application and try again.

Comment: Yoshi_64 unfortunately that popup message does not even appear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go to the device tab (where the devices and emulators are), click your device and then go to the logcat tab again?